# Uploading MP3 files for analysis with spotify audio feature api

Tags: spotify

I was going through the  following link for spotify audio features extraction api,

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-audio-features/

and I was wondering if there is any way I can upload my own track (MP3 file) and get these audio feature without having to specify a spotify id?

I found out that Echo nest has some APIs where  we can upload our own tracks for analysis
http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/track.html

Does Spotify have a similar track upload feature?. (I do know that Echo nest is migrating to Spotify). Any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> and I was wondering if there is any way I can upload my own track (MP3
>   file) and get these audio feature without having to specify a spotify
>   id?

No, you can't unfortunately.

*Source: I work at Spotify.*

Comment: What about EchoNest then?

Comment: It used to be possible with Echonest, in fact my app depended on it (dorienherremans.com/dance). I hope it will be possible to port this at some point.

Comment: Are there any plant to implement this feature?