# Echonest track/upload gives "not allowed to call this method"

Tags: echonest

I'm attempting to call the [track/upload method](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/track.html#upload) as given in the PAI documentation, but I always get the response that I'm "not allowed to call this method". Is the method deprecated after they were bought by Spotify?

According to [Uploading MP3 files for analysis with spotify audio feature api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37202032/uploading-mp3-files-for-analysis-with-spotify-audio-feature-api) Spotify does not have such a function.

Comment: i think they provide this feature for commercial users only

Comment: @GauravSharma Or is it that they shut it down without saying so clearly. They are owned by Spotify now so why should they bother with tracks not on Spotify.

Comment: @S Vilcans yes but i didn't try using it with the spotify API. Spotify documentation clearly specify that they support this feature

Comment: have a look here https://developer.spotify.com/spotify-echo-nest-api/#track-analysis

Comment: @GauravSharma It clearly says it's for tracks "either identified by their ID or through search" so no audio analysis.